# Installing Ruby gems-permissions error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Trying to install Ruby Gems (actually sinatra) on iMac-
Get these error messages

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory

 rubygems-2.1.11 mark$ gem install sinatra

 rubygems-2.1.11 mark$ ruby setup.rb
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
  Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/gauntlet_rubygems.rb
```

Any easy solutions?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is to *not* try to modify the version of Ruby that Apple installed for their own use.

Instead, use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) to install Ruby in a sandbox in your home directory where you can fold, spindle and mutilate it all you want.

If you go with RVM, take the time to read the entire installation page before beginning your install. Failure to do that is the #1 cause for problems using RVM. RBEnv on the other hand, is simpler but not as "feature-packed". Personally, I use and recommend the later.